# Align stack panel according to one of sub element

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a button with a StackPanel, I want to align StackPanel to center according to first TextBox (maintext).

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource NumPadStyle}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Tag="7" >
   <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource NumPadMainText}" Name="maintext">7</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource NumPadSubText}" Name="subtext">PQRS</TextBlock>
   </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

current:
[image: current]

desired:
[image: desired]

Comment: Is it Mandatory that the first letter be in the middle? Or can it me next to the middle.

Comment: @LupuSilviu first letter has to be in the middle.

Comment: can you please show how your buttons are arranged? withing Grid?

Comment: @RackM https://imgur.com/a/rKKkYpH, Numbers must be aligned.

Comment: @cagdas I mean to say full XAML code

Comment: @RackM https://pastebin.com/nTCV5v6m

Answer (score 0):

Taking into consideration that it seems that all the buttons have the same size, you could use a grid with Columns of even size, to be sure that your texts will be positions in the same way in all the buttons.

```
  <Button Style="{StaticResource NumPadStyle}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2" Tag="7">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                       Style="{StaticResource NumPadMainText}" Name="maintext">7</TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                       Style="{StaticResource NumPadSubText}" 
                       Name="subtext">PQRS</TextBlock>
        </Grid>
   </Button>
```

LE: You can replace the `Width="Auto"` value in the Column to a fixed value, like `Width="20"` or something, in case you want all NumPadSubTexts to start from the same location in all buttons.

Comment: It doesnt work, all maintexts must be on middle of the buttons.

Comment: @cagdas, I have updated the solution. See if now it is ok.

Answer (score 0):

Set **MinWidth** (adjust it coherently with the fontsize) to StackPanel:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" MinWidth="35">
     <TextBlock  Style="{StaticResource NumPadMainText}" Name="maintext">7</TextBlock>
     <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource NumPadSubText}" Name="subtext">PQRS</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```